# PHP Send Mail duplicating body

Tags: php, sendmail

I have this script which sends an email for users to activate their accounts on my website, its working fine my only problem is that its sending the body of the message twice, Can anybody see and explain why?

```
$toemail = $_POST['produgg_email'];
// Send activation email 
$to = $toemail;
$subject = "Website Activation";
$headers = "From: support@website\r\n" .
$body = "To activate your website.co.uk please click <a href='http://www.website.co.uk/activateuser.php?email=$toemail'>here</a>";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean that it is sending the whole message twice, or that it is duplicating the `$body` text inside one message?

Comment: Also, please read up on email injection attacks.  By using `$_POST['produgg_email']` directly into the `$to` without validation, your script is open to becoming a spam source.  http://www.phpsecure.info/v2/article/MailHeadersInject.en.php

Comment: Sorry Michael I had to nip out after posting this question, Thanks for the information regarding SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Why did you remove the code? This makes the question completely useless for anyone in the future. Rolled back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pasted the code? If so, you have a dot instead of a ; at line 5...

Comment: Nice catch.  That must be it.